# On Abel summation $\sum_{e<n\leq x}\left(\mu(n)\cdot\int_2^n\frac{ds}{\log s}\right)$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: proof-verification, summation, indefinite-integrals, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

By Abel's identity for $Li (x)=\int_2^x\frac{ds}{\log s}$, $a(n)=\mu(n)$ the Möbius function and $[y=e,x]$ (see Theorem 4.2, page 77 of [1]) and an application of Fundamental Calculus Theorem we obtain

$$\sum_{e <n\leq x}\mu (n)Li (n)=\sum_{e<n\leq x}\mu(n)\cdot\left(\int_2^n\frac{ds}{\log s}\right)=M(x)\cdot\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}-\int_e^x\frac{M(t)}{\log t}dt,$$
where $M(x)=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\mu(n)$. Since we have the obvious estimating $M(x)=O(x)$ we have 
$$\int_e^x\frac{M(t)}{\log t}dt=O\left(\int_e^x\frac{t}{\log t}dt\right)$$
I believe that $\int_e^x (t/\log t) dt$ is computed using definition of exponential integral, by I don't know how made it (by change of variables we obtain $\int_1^{\log x}(e^{2t}/t) dt$ ).

My

> **Question.** a) A proof verification of previous computations is required and will be appreciated. b) How bound in a more accurate way, if it is possible, $\int_e^x M(t)/\log t dt$? c) How bound $\int_e^x t/\log t dt$ (I search an answer to c), regardless of your answer to b) I say a big oh- bound too)?

Thanks in advance. My goal is strengthen my standard maths and encourage people.

References:

[1] Apostol, Introduction to analytitc Number Theory, Springer 1978.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Your computations are correct, the only thing I note that the function $\int_{2}^{n}dt/\log\left(t\right)$ has a name; it's the logaritmic integral, and the standard notation is $\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)$.

b-c) Assuming Riemann hypothesis, we can estimate the Merten's function as $M\left(x\right)=O\left(x^{1/2+\epsilon}\right),\,\forall\epsilon>0$. Actually there are some improvements of this bound, for more details see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0723). About the integrals, the only “closed form” you can obtain involving the Exponential integral function, but if you want a “more tractable” form we can use the well-knonw asymptotic $$\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)\sim\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}
 $$ hence, assuming RH, $$\int_{e}^{x}\frac{M\left(t\right)}{\log\left(t\right)}dt=O\left(\frac{x^{3/2+\epsilon}}{\log\left(x\right)}\right),\,\forall\epsilon>0$$ and without RH, $$\int_{e}^{x}\frac{M\left(t\right)}{\log\left(t\right)}dt=O\left(\frac{x^{2}}{\log\left(x\right)}\right).$$

Comment: Very thanks much,  I am interesting in learn this kind of computations to improve few my mathematics,  thanks @MarcoCantarini

Comment: I take time to study this in detail,  thanks